# android dalvikvm error:threadid=17

Tags: android, performance, android-logcat

1.Sometimes my app is running too slowly, and the log always print this error,although the app still continue running.

```
E/dalvikvm(17325): threadid=17: created from interp,name=auth
E/dalvikvm(17325): threadid=17: calling run(),name=auth
E/dalvikvm(17325): threadid=17: exiting,name=auth
E/dalvikvm(17325): threadid=17: created from interp,name=auth
```

2.The log prompted me this info:

```
I/Choreographer(17325): Skipped 227 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to profile your app to figure out where the slowdown is.  Look at the running threads in the DDMS view and if that does not reveal anything, look into gathering a [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html).

As for your messages, the first group looks somewhat normal, you'll see the second fairly frequently if you're running on an emulator.  On a real device, you'll see them also, but not as often.  227 frames does seem like an awful log though.  Make sure you are doing all non-UI work on background threads.  The systrace will help identify methods that are taking a long time.